# How can I implement an Instagram photo filter?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, instagram, lightroom

I've been wondering, **what theory and algorithms are behind** Instagram(and any other) **photo filters**, Lightroom presets, etc?

How does one create new filters? Manually tweaking Hue, Saturation and Brightness until an image looks nice?
How can I implement one in `Python`/`Java`?

What keywords should I search for to get some understanding in this area?

Comment: Read a book on image-processing fundamentals. Actually reading some Wikipedia articles should be enough to understand. Your question is too broad and can be answered by entering "image-processing filter" into any websearch

Comment: Maybe this repo could help you for both the implementation and the words to look for : https://github.com/Zomato/AndroidPhotoFilters

Comment: `OpenCV` is very useful for image tweaking. It has API on Python, so you can try it out. It's the most popular framework out there, so there's plenty of tutorials.

The LightRoom presets are a bit different -- while photo filters uses RGB format (encoded in JPEG, PNG, etc.), Lightroom works also with RAW files -- image files that contain information about camera lens (distortion, aberration, etc.), camera matrix chip (how much light reached each sensor), etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Python library [pilgram](https://pypi.org/project/pilgram/) like in this example. It provides instagram filters and different blending modes (_1977, aden, brannan, brooklyn, clarendon, earlybird, gingham, hudson, inkwell, kelvin, lark, lofi, maven, mayfair, moon, nashville, perpetua, reyes, rise, slumber, stinson, toaster, valencia, walden, willow, xpro2).

```py
from PIL import Image
import pilgram

im = Image.open('sample.jpg')
pilgram.aden(im).save('sample-aden.jpg')
```

There is also [implementation](https://github.com/acoomans/instagram-filters) of some filters and [Gotham filter](https://github.com/lukexyz/CV-Instagram-Filters), but pilgram is better.